# Qt save strings to JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

Im trying to save my waypoints into .json file, but it is always saving the wrong string.. which I dont know where it is coming.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < path->GetPointCount(); i++) {
    Vector lonlatalt;
    path->GetPointLocation(i).GetGeodetic(&lonlatalt);
    sstr << "waypoint";
    sstr << i;
    sstr << " ";
    sstr << lonlatalt.x;
    sstr << " ";
    sstr << lonlatalt.y;
    sstr << " 0.0";
    sstr << std::endl;

    std::string alt = " 0.0";

    QJsonObject json;
    json["waypoint"+i] = lonlatalt.x, lonlatalt.y, alt;
    QJsonDocument json_doc(json);
    QString json_string = json_doc.toJson();
    QString filename = "./tempwpf";

    QFile save_file(filename);
    if(!save_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        qDebug() << "failed to open save file";
    }
    save_file.write(json_string.toLocal8Bit());
    save_file.close();
}
```

The output of json file should be:

```
{
  "waypoint0": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint1": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint2": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint3": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint4": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint5": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint6": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
json["waypoint"+i] = lonlatalt.x, lonlatalt.y, alt;
```

There's not a single right thing in this line.

```
"waypoint"+i
```

`"waypoint"` is a string literal, i.e. an array of `char`, which decays to a pointer to its first element; now, if you sum an integer to a pointer, you get an incremented pointer, i.e. a pointer that points `i` elements after the first.

Hence, here you are effectively taking a substring of `"waypoint"` starting at the `i`-th character. `"waypoint"+1` => `"aypoint"`; `"waypoint"+2` => `"ypoint"` and so on.

Given that you are using Qt and `QString` anyhow to put this into the JSON document, you can simply use the Qt string formatting methods; so, on the left hand side you can do:

```
json[QString("waypoint%1").arg(i)]
```

---

On the right hand side, it's all wrong again; here you are mistakingly using the comma operator, which evaluates the expressions at both its sides and discards the left one; so when you write

```
lonlatalt.x, lonlatalt.y, alt
```

you are actually writing

```
(lonlatalt.x, lonlatalt.y), alt
```

which boils down to plain `alt`.

Now, if you want to format this as a comma-separated string, you can again use the `QString` methods:

```
json[QString("waypoint%1").arg(i)] = QString("%1, %2, 0.0").arg(lonlatalt.x, 0, 'f', 5).arg(lonlatalt.y, 0, 'f', 5)
```

---

Finally, you are creating/saving a new QJsonDocument at each iteration, so every time you create a file with just one waypoint and overwrite the previous one. You should move the creation/save outside of the loop:

```
QJsonObject json;
```

goes before the `for`

```
json["waypoint"+i] = lonlatalt.x, lonlatalt.y, alt;
```

remains inside, and all the rest outside. Notice that even the code to save is suboptimal: `json_doc.toJson()` returns a `QByteArray` already in UTF-8 (which is generally used as the "canonical" encoding for JSON); you are reconverting it to a `QString` and then converting it back to an 8 bit encoding (which is lossy and most probably unintended).

Also, you check if the file was opened successfully, and write on it even in case of error - that's definitely a bad idea.

Finally, `close()` is not needed - it's performed automatically when the `QFile` goes out of scope.

To sum it up:

```
QFile save_file("./tempwpf");
if(save_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
    QJsonDocument json_doc(json);
    save_file.write(json_string.toJson());
} else {
    qDebug() << "failed to open save file";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a bit, but I see only one waypoint in JSON.. although I set 6 waypoints.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo; now it should be fixed.

Comment: Ah well, of course... you are also creating a new document at each iteration instead of adding to the same one, saving each time, so the last one wins. You have to move the document instantiation/save outside of the loop.

Comment: Hello again, do you know, why json is sorting them himself and how can I get it resolved https://pastebin.com/NpuiSgFg?

Comment: A JSON object has no inherent ordering; it may be output (and loaded) in whatever order your JSON library likes most. If you want a sequence where the order of values is preserved use a JSON array.

Comment: Thank you a lot. But with this code now, I didn't see waypoint at the beginning. `json.push_back(QString("waypoint%1").arg(i) = QString("%1, %2, 0.0").arg(lonlatalt.x, 0, 'f', 5).arg(lonlatalt.y, 0, 'f', 5));`

Comment: Thus is all wrong again. But this question is now resolved, post a new question with the exact new problem (and in particular, what you are trying to achieve ultimately, because IMO most of the confusion lies there).